# How to call another java program using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The following code(when executed) prompts the user to enter any java class name to execute.

```
import java.io.*;
public class exec {

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);

        System.out.println("Enter the java class name");
        String s=br.readLine();

        Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);

        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
        String line=null;
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch(Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code works fine if I'm using command prompt and I'm able to execute another java program. But I'm unable to do the same using eclipse.No output or error is showing up once I enter the java class name.

I'm new to eclipse. Need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "execute" a java class, so your code as posted can't work.

Instead, you'll need to execute "java" and pass to it the classpath and class name as parameters, something like this:

```
String s = br.readLine();

String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "/some/path/to/your/jar/file", s};

Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: which path do i need to add in "/some/path/to/your/jar/file".And should i add the class path of the java class i'm calling in "-cp".

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear that "/some/path/to/your/jar/file" was the path of the jar file that contains the class you want to run,  ie the classpath. If you have dependencies (other jars your jar needs to run) put all the jars in a directory and make the classpath that directory. I tested this code and it works for me, assuming "s" is "com.mycompany.MyClass" for example

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you again. I'm really confused with the path.I'm trying in this way `String[] cmd={"java","C:/Users/BHARAT/workspace/Testing",s};` In this line C:/... is the path of the project in which all the classes are located. Is this correct?

Comment: No. Just copy my code *exactly* but with the path to your jars! Let's put it this way: Find the command that works in windows, for example let's say this command works: `java -cp C:/Users/BHARAT/workspace/Testing com.bharat.util.TestClass`, then your code would be `String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "C:/Users/BHARAT/workspace/Testing", s};`, where `s = "com.bharat.util.TestClass";`. Every "word" of the command is an element of the `cmd` array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working. I was copying the wrong path every time.

Comment: Hi. I have 1 more question to ask you. I also want to pass a value X along with the cmd in `Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` so that the value X will be used in that java class as a command line argument

Comment: i'm using this code for executing another java class `String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "C:/Users/BHARAT/workspace/Testing/bin", s}; Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` I should be able to pass a value along with this.

Comment: Just add more elements to the `cmd` array. For example, to pass the two arguments "foo" and "bar" to the main method, use this: `String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "C:/Users/BHARAT/workspace/Testing/bin", s, "foo", "bar"}`.  Basically, every word you would use on the command line is another element of the `cmd` array.

Comment: i'm struck once more. I wanted to pass a string and i'm doing in this way `String str="XYZ";` `String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "C:/Users/BHARAT/workspace/Testing/bin",s, "str"};` No output nor error is showing up.

Comment: `String str="XYZ"; String[] cmd = {"java", "-cp", "C:/Users/BHARAT/workspace/Testing/bin",s, str};` - no quotes around `str`, otherwise you are literally sending the String `"str"`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just enter the name of the class, or do you also enter the directory of where the program is located? I think it doesn't work in eclipse because you need to specify where the file is... like C:\Users\Me\workspace\ProjectName\src\filename

Comment: if i use command prompt i'll enter 'java classname'. but this is not working in eclipse

Comment: In eclipse, try typing in the location of the file and see if it works.